# Is it possible to write this algorithm in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this algorithm

- Input: a transferred transaction table T
- Output: a table FP
- Procedure:

  - For items with the first identical tid in the table T 0 insert into the table FP
  - For items with the other identical tids in the table T 0 insertFP (items);

---

```
insertFP (items) 
count := 1; 
curpath := null;
if FP has an item f = i1 (the ﬁrst item in the items) and f. path = null 
   for each item ik in the items 
       insert ik into the table FP;
       curpath += ik;
else
   for each item ik in the items 
       if FP has not an item f = ik 
           insert ik into the table FP; 
       else
           if f. path != ik. path 
              insert ik into the table FP; 
            else
               curcount = ik. count + 1; 
               update the table FP; 
        curpath += ik;
```

I already get the first identical tid in table T, and also get the other identical tids, but I didn't know how to process it in php language.
So the question is, is it possible to write this algorithm in mysql?